# xscreensaver sometimes unlocks locked screen automatically, after returning from monitor standby mode

Tags: login, authentication, power-management, xscreensaver

I am using `xscreensaver` to lock my screen. Additionally to that, my monitor goes to "standby" , i.e turn display off, after 30 minutes of inactivity.

It has happened to me twice now, that I have locked my screen, using  `xscreensaver-command --lock` and when I came back after few hours and moved my mouse, the monitor came back from standby but instead of the expected xscreensaver login window, I was dropped directly into my desktop session - without having to authenticate.

I don't know whether there is any correlation with the power management feature, but it did not happen to me before when I was not using automatic monitor suspend.

Also, I don't have any `.Xauthority` file in my home, but again not sure whether that is relevant.

I am using Debian Wheezy and LXDE

Can somebody please suggest how to investigate this problem ?

```
$ xdpyinfo
name of display:    :0.0
version number:    11.0
vendor string:    The X.Org Foundation
vendor release number:    11204000
X.Org version: 1.12.4
maximum request size:  16777212 bytes
motion buffer size:  256
bitmap unit, bit order, padding:    32, LSBFirst, 32
image byte order:    LSBFirst
number of supported pixmap formats:    7
supported pixmap formats:
    depth 1, bits_per_pixel 1, scanline_pad 32
    depth 4, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 8, bits_per_pixel 8, scanline_pad 32
    depth 15, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 16, bits_per_pixel 16, scanline_pad 32
    depth 24, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
    depth 32, bits_per_pixel 32, scanline_pad 32
keycode range:    minimum 8, maximum 255
focus:  window 0x1e00004, revert to Parent
number of extensions:    26
    BIG-REQUESTS
    Composite
    DAMAGE
    DOUBLE-BUFFER
    DPMS
    DRI2
    Generic Event Extension
    MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    MIT-SHM
    RANDR
    RECORD
    RENDER
    SECURITY
    SHAPE
    SYNC
    X-Resource
    XC-MISC
    XFIXES
    XFree86-DGA
    XFree86-VidModeExtension
    XINERAMA
    XInputExtension
    XKEYBOARD
    XTEST
    XVideo
    XVideo-MotionCompensation
default screen number:    0
number of screens:    1

screen #0:
  dimensions:    1920x1080 pixels (508x285 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
  depths (7):    24, 1, 4, 8, 15, 16, 32
  root window id:    0x6f
  depth of root window:    24 planes
  number of colormaps:    minimum 1, maximum 1
  default colormap:    0x20
  default number of colormap cells:    256
  preallocated pixels:    black 0, white 16777215
  options:    backing-store NO, save-unders NO
  largest cursor:    64x64
  current input event mask:    0x7a003c
    ButtonPressMask          ButtonReleaseMask        EnterWindowMask          
    LeaveWindowMask          StructureNotifyMask      SubstructureNotifyMask   
    SubstructureRedirectMask FocusChangeMask          PropertyChangeMask       
  number of visuals:    3
  default visual id:  0x21
  visual:
    visual id:    0x21
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x22
    class:    DirectColor
    depth:    24 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
  visual:
    visual id:    0x6d
    class:    TrueColor
    depth:    32 planes
    available colormap entries:    256 per subfield
    red, green, blue masks:    0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff
    significant bits in color specification:    8 bits
```

Comment: Can you add the output from `xdpyinfo` to your question?

Comment: @Daniel Amaya - I have updated my question with `xdpyinfo` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely say this sounds like a bug. My suggestion, if you're going to use xscreensaver allow it to handle power management. At the command line type `xscreensaver-demo`, and in the GUI go to the Advanced tab and make sure 'Power Management Enabled' is checked (also tweak the settings how you'd like them to be).

As well, start xscreensaver from the command-line with `xscreensaver -log ~/xscreensaver.log` and see what the log says when this happens.

Comment: what did you learn from the `xdpyinfo` output ?

Comment: I was looking specifically for this `DPMS`, to ensure xscreensaver was compiled with DPMS (display power management signaling). If it wasn't, then my assumption that it was interfering DPMS provided by X or your BIOS would have been completely incorrect, and any suggestions I would have had, short of logging, would have been useless to you.

Comment: and could the missing `.Xauthority` have any effect on proper functioning of `xscreensaver` ? I think, I might have deleted `.Xauthority` because it was empty.

Comment: Let's take the discussion to chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17983/xscreensaver